# Median of string values in a Pandas Series (or GroupBy Object) using built-in methods

Tags: python, pandas, string, median

I have a dataset [US Baby Names](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/06_Stats/US_Baby_Names/US_Baby_Names_right.csv) that contains a "Name" column. Even though it doesn't make much sense to do so, I am trying to find the median name in that column.
i.e. after arranging the names in ascending order, based on the frequency of the names, there'll be a "middle value", and that's what I want to find without having to actually sort the entire column (Pandas Series) and then find the middlemost name. So I need a simple, built-in way to find the median name.

~*~

> EDIT [5:51 am Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)]: The median name should be based on alphabetical/lexicographic order of names.
> Also, here is some part of the csv file (first line is the header):

```
,Id,Name,Year,Gender,State,Count
11349,11350,Emma,2004,F,AK,62
11350,11351,Madison,2004,F,AK,48
11351,11352,Hannah,2004,F,AK,46
11352,11353,Grace,2004,F,AK,44
11353,11354,Emily,2004,F,AK,41
11354,11355,Abigail,2004,F,AK,37
```

~*~

I've tried the built-in pandas median() method, but it doesn't really work for non-numeric values despite setting the `numeric_only` attribute as `False`:

```py
import pandas as pd
baby_names = pd.read_csv(
    "Pandas_DataMart\\DataMart\\06_Stats\\US_Baby_Names\\US Baby Names.xlsx")

print(baby_names['Name'].median(numeric_only=False))
```

There's a bunch of error lines that trace their way through the internal working of the median() method, but ultimately I get this:

```
TypeError: could not convert string to float: 'Emma'
```

So, doesn't seem to work for non-numeric values. Or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the full error message for reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 720, in nanmedian
values = values.astype("f8")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Emma'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\...\BabyNames.py", line 18, in <module>
print(baby_names['Name'].median(numeric_only=False))
File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10802, in median
return NDFrame.median(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10374, in median
return self._stat_function(
File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10354, in _stat_function
return self._reduce(
File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4392, in _reduce
return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 156, in f
result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 723, in nanmedian
raise TypeError(str(err)) from err
TypeError: could not convert string to float: 'Emma'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### original answer: median by count

Assuming you need the name with the median value of counts, use a custom function. Count the frequencies with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) then get the middle value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']})

def count_median(s):
    c = s.value_counts()
    return c.index[len(c)//2]

out = df['names'].agg(count_median)
```

Output: `'A'`

##### alternative: median by lexicographic order

If you want the median/middle value of the lexicographically sorted names, then you must sort:

```
df['names'].sort_values().iloc[len(df)//2]
```

Output: `'C'`

Or if you want the first value if the length of the data is even:

```
df['names'].sort_values().iloc[(len(df)-1)//2]
```

Output: `'B'`

You can make things sightly more efficient by only sorting half of the data with [`numpy.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

```
mid = (len(df)-1)//2
out = np.partition(df['names'], mid)[mid]
```

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate your speedy reply, but for the data you've provided, wouldn't ['B','C'] be the median? Median of ordinal data is a bit weird. Maybe I should clarify that I need the median name in alphabetic/lexicographic order.

Comment: I thought you wanted based on the frequencies? Here B:1, A:2, C:3, A is the median

Comment: "*after arranging the names in ascending order, based on the frequency of the names, there'll be a "middle value"*", this is very different from "*I need the median name in alphabetic/lexicographic order*"

Comment: Yeah, I realized the ambiguity in my question. However, is it clear(er) now?

Comment: Yes, then you need to sort and slice.

Comment: Note that a median is usually one value, not two (like a mode). For numerical values you have different ways of handling the case of even data (mean of the medians). Here you can choose to return both values. For fun you could even take half of each name, "yes I'm talking about you Abigison" :p

Comment: Well, thank you for bearing with me! It seems that there's no way to do this without sorting the pandas series first, eh? That is unfortunate. Nevertheless, you answered my question(s), so I'll upvote this answer. I'll still wait for another answer, just in case an even better method exists to find the lexicographic mean of string-data.

Comment: You can actually avoid sorting the whole array using `numpy.partition`, this will be a bit more efficient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255044/discussion-between-mjk-and-mozway).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use numpy to do this

```
import pandas as pd
baby_names = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/06_Stats/US_Baby_Names/US_Baby_Names_right.csv")
npk  = baby_names.to_numpy()
median = npk[:, 2][len(npk)//2]
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
baby_names = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/06_Stats/US_Baby_Names/US_Baby_Names_right.csv")
median = baby_names["Name"][len(baby_names)//2]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! The data is not sorted lexicographically by baby-names, unfortunately, so this straightforward approach of jumping to the middle index doesn't work. I was looking for a built-in method to find lexicographic median in case I missed something while researching this issue.